# Get all handlebars expression from a div or template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebar template and all i want is to get me all the handlebar expression from the div ?

**Html Code**

```
    <div id="comp_login_i18n">
        <form name="loginForm">
            <table>
                <tr class="requiredField">
                    <td>
                        <label>{{content.token1Label}}</label>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <input type="text">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="requiredField">
                    <td>
                        <label>{{content.token2Label}}</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableWidth" colspan="2">
                        <button {{action submitForm}} class="submit" type="button">{{content.button}}</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>


</script>
```

I am writing a method which takes all the handlebar expression from this div and change the label according to langauge selected. I dont know how to get the handlebars expressions inside this div . Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against trying to construct template files on-the-fly. 
Better inject a "i18n" property inside the context of the template and change it according to the language you selected.

Server side pseudo code:

```
language = getUserLanguage();//user's desired language
data = ...; //data that is needed for your templates (other that i18n stuff)
data.i18n = getStringsForLanguage(language);//get strings for selected language
render(template, data);//invoking template rendering
```

Template:

```
...
<label>{{i18n.token1Label}}</label>
...
```

Then, somewhere you need to define strings for each language (to get in `getStringsForLanguage`) f.ex:

en.strings:

```
token1Label = This is token1Label in English
```

de.strings:

```
token1Label = This is token1Label in German
```

Comment: i am using ember and i have stucked where all i want is the handlebar expression in div and after i get that expression all i do is assign expression array to objects(key's) array and i am done but i cant fins anywhere to get the expression of handlebar inside the current div